# How to change the color of a UIButton: The signup button in Parse`s PFLoginViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, parse-platform

How can I change the (background) color of the signup button in Parse`s`PFLoginViewController`?

I have tried:

```
PFLogInViewController *logInViewController = [[PFLogInViewController alloc] init];
logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsLogInButton | PFLogInFieldsPasswordForgotten | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton ;

logInViewController.logInView.signUpButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This is my result:

[image]

How can the color be set correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not been able to change the color of the button directly. Normally, I'd accomplish via `setTintColor:`. I was able to achieve the changed background color by actually changing the background image using the completion block, like this:

```
        PFLogInViewController *login = [[PFLogInViewController alloc]init];
        login.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:^{
            [login.logInView.signUpButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"restBtn@2x"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [login.logInView.signUpButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"restBtn@2x"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        }];
```

Just make sure you have included your desired red button image in your project somewhere so the name resolution works.

EDIT: As stated by Dmitry, it may be wise to configure the desired image for each UIButton control state that matters to you. Additionally, I had hoped I could pass a collection of UIControlStates, such as

```
[login.logInView.signUpButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"restBtn@2x"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateNormal];
```

for a single button and image combo, but it didn't appear to work.

Comment: think that you need to set up images for all required states, not only for UIControlStateNormal

Comment: I think I agree with you. I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for calling out the other control states.

Comment: Works, but the bottom answer is the best since it doesn't involve images.

Answer (score 8):

Change the background image to nil, and then set the button's background color:

```
[logInViewController.logInView.signUpButton setBackgroundImage:nil
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
logInViewController.logInView.logInButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: Good answer! Thank you